# Is there some software available to centrally manage APC IP enabled PDUs?

Tags: ip, apc, power-distribution-unit, apcupsd

I am not looking for a recommendation of which one to use, just an answer as the whether anything to do this exists.  We have a few dozen [AP7921](http://www.apc.com/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=AP7921) & similar units that until now we have managed on an idivudual basis.  Already collect power usage info using SNMP & Cacti but I want to know; is there any software available (Open Source, Free or Commercial) that would allow me to manage and configure a few dozen of these devices?

At a minimum I would like to be able to see the state of and switch ports.  Even better if I can see the labels and update port names.  Better still if most of the switches configurable items could be played with from a single pane of glass, as they say.

Looking around the www and on server**fault** I can see that a few people suggest [OpenNMS](http://www.opennms.org/) for monitoring.  It does not look like that will give me more than Read access though?

I have also started looking into [apcupsd](http://www.apcupsd.com/) but that looks more geared towards controlling UPS systems, so I am unsure if it is suitable for multiport PDUs.

Any reports of success doing the above, software to investigate and so forth are welcome as comments.  Please only put an answer if you can confirm that "Yes, such software exists" (even better if you can tell me what).  I have already spent a few hours digging around without much success, I am clearly using a wrong keyword somewhere as I cannot believe that nothing exists to do this,.

Comment: "Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations" I explicity stated at the start of the question "I am not looking for a recommendation of which one to use, just an answer as the whether anything to do this exists.".  That is not an obscure A is better than B question it is a True/False answer.  I accept that given enough time the answer might change but that is true of almost all things.  

I agree that I digressed a bit, but only to show I had made some effort to find an answer myself.  As it was SvW probably answered the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is an SNMP client and the PowerNet MIB from APC and you can do what you want. At $oldjob, I had written a perl script that could switch/powercycle based on computer names, it was basically reading port mappings from a database and sending SNMP commands to the appropriate unit and took just a few hours to write.

Comment: Thank you SvW.  That answers my question as a "No, nothing exists at present".  I wanted to know if it was worth spending the time to write something that either used the SNMP interface or the CLI one.

I already have things setup to monitor the PDUs.  Writing a program from scratch that checked on their names, labels, FW versions and could modify the same sounded like a fair bit of work.  I'll know my options are code it myself or live without when I next get back to this.